# R: Undefined Columns Selected Error when Subsetting DF

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

I have a dataframe data with the following structure:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  4391 obs. of  53 variables
```

When I try to subset it to get the top 100 rows using

```
data100 = data[1:100,]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(X[[i]], ...) : undefined columns selected
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - I needed to use

```
as.data.frame(data)
```

before subsetting because tbl_df is not subsettable the same way as a data frame. This was needed due to using dplyr earlier and it outputting a table instead of a df.

Comment: You might have some larger issue you may wish to investigate, because `as.tbl(mtcars)[1:10, ]` (example) works fine.  Seems strange that you would need `as.data.frame()` to solve it.

Comment: i would say more than likely you forgot that comma

Comment: Comma was definitely there, the code is just as copied, that was one of the first things I double-checked. Not sure why as.data.frame() worked, but it's all running fine now